# What are the preprocessor symbols defined for .Net 5.0?

Tags: c#, .net-5

What would you use in a `#if` when targeting **.Net 5.0**?

i.e. for the other frameworks

**.NET Framework**

> NETFRAMEWORK, NET20, NET35, NET40, NET45, NET451, NET452, NET46, NET461, NET462, NET47, NET471, NET472, NET48

**.NET Standard**

> NETSTANDARD, NETSTANDARD1_0, NETSTANDARD1_1, NETSTANDARD1_2, NETSTANDARD1_3, NETSTANDARD1_4, NETSTANDARD1_5, NETSTANDARD1_6, NETSTANDARD2_0, NETSTANDARD2_1

**.NET Core**

> NETCOREAPP, NETCOREAPP1_0, NETCOREAPP1_1, NETCOREAPP2_0, NETCOREAPP2_1, NETCOREAPP2_2, NETCOREAPP3_0, NETCOREAPP3_1

Comment: seems this [hasn't been decided yet](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/17911)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set the build output to "detailed" and try this *today*, you should see something like (among the rest of the output - near a `csc.exe` mention):

> ```
> /define:TRACE;DEBUG;NETCOREAPP;NETCOREAPP5_0
> ```

so: `NETCOREAPP5_0` is what you're looking for - but: whether this stays the same *at launch* may change. You can repeat the same process at a later date to find out.

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor definitions changed in [dotnet/sdk#12124](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/12124) to fit [this design](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/f1b3661/accepted/2020/net5/net5.md#preprocessor-symbols) before .NET 5 was released.  The released version defines:

```
NETCOREAPP
NET5_0
```

This is now also documented in [#if (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if#remarks).  It **does not** define `NETCOREAPP5_0` anymore.